# Ionic application's apk not working properly

Tags: ionic-framework

My ionic application runs properly in the browser but when I build its apk and run on an Android device it does not work properly. It is not showing pictures in app and also layout of app is totally lost on the Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with this exact same problem.

This is caused by the use of relative paths when referencing your images. This doesn't cause a problem when you run your app with `ionic serve`, but when you build your app to run on a device this does not work anymore.

You have to reference your images by using a path such as `assets/images/image.svg`

Hope this helps!